# Using Hostname with a Page Level Custom Variable

Tags: google-analytics

I've got a site tagged with a custom variable used to determine "page type", which is set to a page level variable:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'PageType', 'List', 3]);
```

This works well, for the most part, as I can report on the number of Page Views for all list pages, for example, and look at metrics across all my list pages on my site.

However, I recently added a mobile site at m.mydomain.com and I'm trying to report on my page types for these mobile page views. I design a simple custom report with page views and visitors by custom variable value 1 and then filter by hostname m.mydomain.com - but now I get very low numbers, far lower than should be there.

Does anyone know if the hostname filter is somehow incompatible with the page level custom variables? Or is there anyother reason why GA might not report this custom variable properly with the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** would be to create separate profiles for your mobile vs. regular site.  Apply a filter on the profiles to either include or exclude traffic based on the domain. How you setup the actual profile filters depends on your setup, but for example, you can have something like this:

```
mobile profile > include "m.mydomain.com"
desktop profile > include "www.mydomain.com"
rollup profile > (no filters, like what you currently have)
```

Or if you have multiple "not mobile" (sub) domains, you could instead do something like this:

```
mobile profile > include "m.mydomain.com"
desktop profile > exclude "m.mydomain.com"
rollup profile > (no filters, like what you currently have)
```

**Option 2** would be to pop an additional custom field with "m.mydomain.com" vs. "www.mydomain.com" and use that as a filter.

**Option 3** Would be to add your domain to your page name. in the _trackPageview call.  By default the reported page name is the relative path of the page.  But you can pop a custom value for that call with something like `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview',location.href.replace(/https?:\/\//,'')]);` This is actually somewhat useful if you want to get into rollup profiles that span multiple domains.

Comment: Are you saying the hostname value is the referrer domain? It sure doesn't seem like it from http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55588: